# Taxonomy terms with image?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Can I associate an image field to a taxonomy term? I need to do this in my panel that lists the children terms (with images to make it look nice) of a parent term page. I have already added image field in vocabulary thus images for each terms.

I'm on D7.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to _display_ the image then? If so you need to provide more info about how you currently render your page/node/whatever.

Comment: Ok. I've edited the "Taxonomy Term Template" in pages/panels. The taxonomy terms showed above are the child terms which I selected from the panel settings. I do see the option of selecting the term image field in the settings but that field shows the current parent term's image not of the children.

Comment: I see. Since having Page manager/Panels pull out related data is _wildly_ different from attaching images to the terms in the first place, which I have already answered, could we open a new question for this?

Comment: Ok I'm posting a new question.

Comment: Care to link to the new question?

Answer (score 7):

In D7 Terms are "entities", which means you can set an image field right on them, just like you could have with CCK in Drupal 6.

Just go to manage fields on whatever vocabulary you want, and you can add the image field.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

In D7 taxonomy is an Entity so you can add fields to it and make more usable. Yes you can add an image field and you can use display formatters to display the image. You can use [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module or [Entity View Mode](https://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module to create new view mode and display it on entity view.

If you want to add term to content, just use [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module not the term reference.

Answer (score 2):

To display the images you assigned to your terms you need to follow the instructions here: https://drupal.org/node/1224916